# How to match exact sentence with spaces and special character in perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am beginner in Perl Regular expression. I am reading contents from a text document and trying to extract the line which exactly matches the required string containing spaces and special characters which is "hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l". Below is contents from the text document

```
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwldbbc01pvs ps -ef |grep mysqld | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwsapbc01pvb ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwsapbc02pvc ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwsapbc03pvg ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwsapbc04pvv ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwadbgw31pvv ps -ef |grep OpenDeploy | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwadbgw32pve ps -ef |grep OpenDeploy | grep -v grep | wc -l
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hwawbgw01pvy ps -ef |grep sayt.*4150 | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

I have written the code

```
my $infile = "InputTextDoc.txt";
my $outfile = "Output.txt";
open(FH, "<$infile") or die "File not found";
open(OP, ">$outfile") or die "Output File not found";
my $str = "hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l"; # which should only match 6th line from text document
while(<FH>)
{
$line = $_;
chomp($line);
if($line =~ m/\b$str\b/)
   {
    print OP "$line\n";
   }
}
close FH;
close OP;
```

Since ps -ef exists in all lines its matching all lines. However, entire string "hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l" unique in text document.
How to match exact string.Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [\Q escape](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html): `\b\Q$str\E\b` instead `\b$str\b` [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/uA4qB3/1).

Comment: You only need to check for `hwsapbc05pvz`, no need to include pipes.

Answer (score 1):

If you include this variable unescaped into the regex, parser uses the pipes

```
hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l
                    ↑ OR      ↑ OR           ↑ OR
```

giving a match on any matching substring. To match all string literally try [\Q escape](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
if($line =~ m/\b\Q$str\E\b/)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uA4qB3/1) or try using [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) `my $escaped_str = quotemeta($str);`

Comment: Thanks man. It working for me. I learnt new regular expression quotemeta

Answer (score 1):

The "|" in your pattern need to be escaped by backslash, and the $str need to have qr in the beginning. Change the 5th line of you script, and it worked on my environment.

```
my $str = qr"hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef \|grep prd \| grep -v grep \| wc -l";
```

Comment: Thanks man, its working fine. However, i cannot use this, because, i am fetching the matching string "$str" from excel sheet. To add escape character for "|", i have to write another function. So i used quotemeta.

Answer (score 1):

subhas Chandra : I have modified your code and have posted it below. This should work fine now.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $infile = "Input.txt";
my $outfile = "Output.txt";
open(FH, "<$infile") or die "File not found";
open(OP, ">$outfile") or die "Output File not found";
my $str = "hwsapbc05pvz ps -ef |grep prd | grep -v grep | wc -l"; # which should only match 6th line from text document
my $finalstr = quotemeta($str);
while(<FH>)
{
my $line = $_;
chomp($line);
if($line =~ m/$finalstr/)
   {
    print OP "$line\n";
   }
}
close FH;
close OP;
```